# how to remove last element in the redux store array?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have following code:

```
const initialState = {
  searchItems: ['Item'],
}
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BACKSPACE_REMOVE_SEARCH_ITEM:
      console.log(state.searchItems);
      return {
        ...state,
        searchItems: [...state.searchItems.splice(-1)],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

but when I try to execute such an action I receive same array as before with 'Item' inside, it doesn't' remove it. Where is a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.splice` returns the deleted elements. Actually, you shouldn't use `.splice` at all since it mutates the original array. I know you are spreading the original one but spread syntax makes shallow copies. So, be careful. `.slice` would be better it also returns the deleted ones. In this case, you need to use a combination of `.slice` and `.concat` probably or you can use `.filter`.

```
return {
    ...state,
    searchItems: state.searchItems.filter( (_,i) => 
        i !== state.searchItems.length-1
    ),
};
```